# My page wont display it keeps saying Jslint Error on my external javascript code

Tags: javascript, css

My page wont display it keeps saying Jslint Error on my external javascript code, but if i include the javascript in head section it will display properly. Am really new to coding so please i don't know what next to look out for.

```
var slideIndex = 0;
showSlides();

function showSlides() {
    var i;
    var slides = document.getElementsByClassName("mySlides");
    var dots = document.getElementsByClassName("dot");

    for (i = 0; i < slides.length; i++) {
        slides[i].style.display = "none";  
    }

    slideIndex++;
    if (slideIndex > slides.length) {slideIndex = 1}   

    for (i = 0; i < dots.length; i++) {
        dots[i].className = dots[i].className.replace(" active", "");
    }

    slides[slideIndex-1].style.display = "block";  
    dots[slideIndex-1].className += " active";
    setTimeout(showSlides, 2000); // Change image every 2 seconds
}
```

Comment: How do you import your external code ?

Comment: <script type="text/javascript" src="fish.js"></script>

Comment: Post jslint error text here. Check include order - you might load a required script after the place it is used.